# Can a mobile phone emit gamma rays?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electronics, batteries, gamma-rays

I heard that inside the battery of mobile phones (but also of other electronic devices) can happen [quantum leaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_electron_transition) that cause the emission of gamma rays photons.

Is this phenomenon really possible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is counterfactual.

Comment: @DavidHammen I don't understand... The question is about physics, so why you think is off-topic? I received some informations about mobile phones that sounded weird to me and since I don't have a solid background in these topics I wanted to know if they were plausible. What do you find counterfactual here?

Comment: No, gamma rays would require million times bigger energy as the electron transitions have. It is probably from some pseudoscientific fake news source. My reason to close this question is that it would be better to not distribute it (what corresponds with the "non-mainstream" close reason).

Comment: @peterh I made a question in order to know if a certain assertion that I heard is verified or not. I wasn't able to find anything about it on the web, so I thought that here I would find an answer. Now I have one and accepted it: I think that the platform was very useful in my case, because it helped me to debunk a source of false informations. Considering the times, if a platform like this can do also this service, it becomes even more valuable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gamma rays are emitted by nuclei or in particle accelerators. The power available in an electronic device has nothing to do with nuclei, currents are motions of electrons in conductor. At most electrons can produce  [x-rays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_spectrum) for example  the [cathode ray tube](https://www.fda.gov/radiation-emittingproducts/resourcesforyouradiationemittingproducts/ucm252764.htm) of the analogue TV, they  do not reach energies of gamma rays.

Maybe people confuse general electromagnetic radiation (see link above), which exists in radio frequency transmissions , and gamma rays which are of very high energy not available to transmitters and receivers.